# Connection refused while downloading Laravel installer - "https://repo.packagist.org/packages.json" file could not be downloaded"

Tags: laravel, composer-php, ubuntu-20.04, php-7.4

I am trying to download the `Laravel` installer using `Composer` for the first time on `Ubuntu 20.04 LTS`.

```
composer global require laravel/installer
```

gives

```
Changed current directory to /home/sandeep/.config/composer

In RemoteFilesystem.php line 560:
                                                                                                           
  The "https://repo.packagist.org/packages.json" file could not be downloaded: failed to open stream: Connection refused
```

**PHP Version:**

```
PHP 7.4.3 (cli) (built: May 26 2020 12:24:22) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.4.0, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.4.3, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
```

**Composer Version**

```
Composer 1.10.1 2020-03-13 20:34:27
```

**Ping Output:**

```
sandeep@sandeep:~$ ping repo.packagist.org
PING org.domain.name (78.47.226.171) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from static.171.226.47.78.clients.your-server.de (78.47.226.171): icmp_seq=1 ttl=49 time=251 ms
64 bytes from static.171.226.47.78.clients.your-server.de (78.47.226.171): icmp_seq=2 ttl=49 time=251 ms
64 bytes from static.171.226.47.78.clients.your-server.de (78.47.226.171): icmp_seq=3 ttl=49 time=251 ms
64 bytes from static.171.226.47.78.clients.your-server.de (78.47.226.171): icmp_seq=4 ttl=49 time=251 ms
64 bytes from static.171.226.47.78.clients.your-server.de (78.47.226.171): icmp_seq=5 ttl=49 time=251 ms
^C
--- org.domain.name ping statistics ---
6 packets transmitted, 5 received, 16.6667% packet loss, time 5007ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 250.508/250.803/251.168/0.231 ms
```

Not sure if this is a configuration or a network issue or something else.

Comment: are you able to open https://repo.packagist.org/packages.json in a browser?

Comment: @JamesClarkDeveloper - No. I get `Site cannot be reached. repo.packagist.org refused to connect.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a network issue.

I had to modify `/etc/resolv.conf`

**`sudo vim /etc/resolv.conf`**

and add

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

Save the file and restart the network.